# lines not showing up on line graph in R when using plot() then points() - problem with subset?

Tags: r, plot, subset, line, points

I am trying to create a line graph. I am able to create the plot but when trying to add `points()` / `lines()` nothing shows up.

`plot(subset(dc, code == "RS")$date, subset(dc, code == "RS")$rp, type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Real price of cement", xlim=c(2005,2020), ylim=c(0,400))`

`title("States: RS, MG, MT, PE", line = 0.3)`

`points(subset(dc, code == "MG")$date, subset(dc, code == "MG")$rp, type = "l", col="red")`

`points(subset(dc, code == "MT")$date, subset(dc, code == "MT")$rp, type = "l",col="yellow")`

`points(subset(dc, code == "PE")$date, subset(dc, code == "PE")$rp, type = "l",col="blue")`

This is especially confusing since I have copied the code from my profs solutions to the problem where the lines do show up. The only thing I altered to the solution was adding `xlim =`because of an error message.
I am also receiving `warning in xy.coords(x, y) : NAs introduced by coercion`. Could this be a problem?

I am wondering whether I need to download another package? Maybe the subset is an issue?

[This is a link to the data](https://elearning.uni-oldenburg.de/sendfile.php?force_download=1&type=0&file_id=90e6851760e95325b7cf112fb2b3a084&file_name=data_cement.csv)

`structure(list(X = 193:194, state = c("RIO GRANDE DO SUL", "RIO GRANDE DO SUL" ), year = c(2004L, 2004L), code = c("RS", "RS"), yearmonthday_str = c(20040101L,  20040201L), date = c("2004-01-01", "2004-02-01"), rp = c(155.802764892578,  154.858352661133)), row.names = 193:194, class = "data.frame")`

[image: This is how the graph is supposed to look]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the new variables to add to the plot in that `xlim` range? Otherwise, without some data it is difficult to say.

Comment: yes, I added the x-axis values that show up in the solution

Comment: Can you post some of your data? You could use `dput()`. I'm assuming `ylim` is also correct.

Comment: I just added the data and a screenshot of how the graph looks in the solution. Yes, I copied `ylim`.

Comment: In order to be able to read the data you should post it in code format, using `dput()` for example. This post might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, I can't really see `date` or `rp` in that picture.

Comment: One other thing, though. Just curious, nothing more. Why do you use `points(data,type="l")` instead of  `lines(data)`?

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me, as you can tell I am quite new to working with R. I posted some code using`dput()`but also the csv.data which I haven't altered in any way.

Comment: I used `points(data, type="l"`because I followed exactly what my prof did. However, I asked myself the same question and tried using `lines(data)`. Neither one showed the lines in the graph.

Comment: I can't access the data since a password is needed, but looking at the two rows of data you posted, I don't see "date", but "year", could that be it?  About `lines` and `points(type="l")`, they are actually the same function, it is just about readability. I think it is easier to read using `lines` here but, as I said, they do the exact same think since they use the same function in the end.

Comment: I just edited the post to show that there is the column `date`. I think this might be where the problem lies. Is this column not numeric because of the dashes? This might explain why I get the error message `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values`

Comment: Could be. Try `date = as.Date(c("2004-01-01", "2004-02-01"))`. Maybe that could be it

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! I used `dc$date <- as.Date(dc$date)`. R didn't seem to recognize this column as numeric values before.